# Unity panel shortcut

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shortcuts

I am a noob gettings started with linux/ubuntu and after reading around I found some advise on lifehacker saying instead of typing

> 'gksu nautilus'

all the time in the terminal when wanting the file browser with root privileges it's easier to just

> "create a panel shortcut"

with

> 'sudo nautilus'

but it does not say **how** to make this panel shortcut.

I am using 14.4, can you give me the steps on how to make this panel shortcut please?
.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279878/how-can-i-put-a-shortcut-to-nautilus-with-root-privileges-in-the-launcher-ubunt).  There's also a tutorial on creating launcher shortcuts at [Ubuntu documentation pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Comment: Been through that link, couldnt get it to work (possibly because I didnt understand it too well being a Linux noob)